# Withdraw upvote from answer after a while

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

I recently ran into a situation where I realized after a while that I shouldn't have upvoted the answer, as it had a loophole.

I went back to the answer and tried to withdraw it, but I couldn't, because it had been a while. Upon attempting to revoke my upvote, I was prompted that it could be done only if the answer is edited.

So, I edited the answer and changed just a few characters and then was able to undo my upvote.

I really do not understand this behaviour: why could I only undo the vote after editing?

Answer (score 3):

It's meant to encourage you to *think about your votes* before you make them.

If you read over something again and realize that you should have voted differently, then you should have thought more carefully about your vote in the first place.

Now, obviously, as a 2k+ user, you're able to make trivial edits and subsequently alter your vote, but lower-rep users would have to make substantial edits and go through the suggested edit approval process before revoking their vote.

If something is clarified in comments that changes your mind, **you should edit that clarification into the question**, because the question wasn't clear enough on that point.

You can only undo your votes after editing because an edit can change the meaning or quality of a post, and you might want to change your vote if such a thing happens.

Comment: *"then you should have thought more carefully about your vote in the first place"* - isn't that like saying you need to be an expert in everything? Or is it saying you should not vote on a subject you have little to know expertise in? I often visit topics looking for answers that I have little to no expertise in (else I would not need to visit them in the first place). And not voting on questions and answer due to lack of subject matter expertise kind of breaks the site's model.

Comment: @jww No, but if you downvote something because it is not useful, not explained well, or low quality, then that's not going to change without an edit. In this case, the error was something the OP missed, so the mechanism is working: it will encourage him/her to more thoroughly consider an answer next time before voting on it.

Comment: Saksham's question is about upvotes and retracting them, not downvotes.

Comment: @jww Yes, but the same logic applies: votes on a post should only have to change because of edits: if it's something you missed, you should have considered the vote more carefully (or, at least, that's how the system is set up). I was addressing your comment with the downvotes: you don't have to know the subject matter to recognize high quality and low quality content.